# Error running make: missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?)

Tags: linux, makefile, debian, phar

I'm trying to get PHP `phar` command line tool installed on my Debian VM, how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373638/how-to-get-where-to-obtain-the-php-phar-command-line-tool?noredirect=1#comment21740410_15373638) described:

> (1) download the php-src, I assume it's in /tmp/php/src
>
> (2) make the dir /tmp/phar
>
> (3) Save [this](http://pastebin.com/UgpaRda1) as /tmp/php-src/ext/phar/Makefile.
>
> (4) cd /tmp/php-src/ext/phar
>
> (5) run `sudo make`

Now after step 5 I get an error:

```
:/tmp/php-src/ext/phar# make
Makefile:11: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
```

As I know, there can be two possible causes for this error message:

1. Tabs in the make file. I've tested the file with `od -t c Makefile`. The file contains no tabs (`\t`).
2. It could be a [bug](http://buildroot-busybox.2317881.n4.nabble.com/Makefile-904-missing-separator-did-you-mean-TAB-instead-of-8-spaces-Stop-td7469.html) of `make` v3.81 and need a [patch](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2010-November/038615.html) or an upgrade to (yet instable: "[Warning: This package is from the **experimental** distribution.](http://packages.debian.org/en/experimental/make)") v3.82. I've [downloaded](http://packages.debian.org/de/experimental/amd64/make/download) and istalled (`dpkg -i make_3.82-1_amd64.deb`) it, but the error is still occuring.

What causes the error? How can it be avoided?

Thx

Comment: The line **should** begin with a tab, not a bunch of spaces.

Comment: I've replaced all 8-spaces sequences with tabs and can execute the make script now. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

(Answered in a comment: See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@Beta wrote:

> The line **should** begin with a tab, not a bunch of spaces.

The OP wrote:

> I've replaced all 8-spaces sequences with tabs and can execute the make script now.

Answer (score -1):

I used:
`cat Makefile|sed "s/        /\t/" > Makefile`